# how to access files on any user system

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
// these files are stored on my system on these path : C:/Users/ABHISHEK/Desktop/Songify-master/Songify-master/assets/images/        
     var gifArr = ['source.gif',
                  'source1.gif',
                  'source2.gif',
                  'source3.gif',
                  'source4.gif',
                  'source5.gif',
                  'source6.gif',
                  'source7.gif',
                  'source9.gif',
                  'source10.gif',
                  'source11.gif',
                  'source12.gif',
                  'source13.gif'
                 ];

    // function to select the random gif andchange the gif after 5 seconds

        function changeGif(){
            setInterval(function(){
                $('.add-gif').css({'background-image': 'url(C:/Users/ABHISHEK/Desktop/Songify-master/Songify-master/assets/images/' + gifArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * gifArr.length)] + ')'}); 
            },
            5000);
        }
```

*the function changeGif() will select the random gif and change the background after 5 seconds. the function will work on my system as I defined the static path in the function.* 
*But I want that the user who downloads my application and run code, then the path will be set according to the user's system.* 
*So how can I get a path of the files according to the user's system?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the relative path of the image from the script file

According to [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url)

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style
>   sheet, not relative to the document

The url is relative to the location of the file, so this should work for you:

```
url('../../images/image.jpg')

$('.add-gif').css('backgroundImage','url(images/'  + gifArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * gifArr.length)] ) );
```

Comment: But how to that. can you brief.

Comment: this the error what i get : GET file:///C:/Users/ABHISHEK/Desktop/images/source7.gif net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: You're in right direction, need to set the path correctly. Now it's looking for the file, but from desktop. Set it from the path of file.

Comment: Where is the file, where jQuery script is executing?

Comment: this is the path of jquery : C:\Users\ABHISHEK\Desktop\Songify-master\Songify-master\assets\jquery\jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: this is index file location : C:\Users\ABHISHEK\Desktop\Songify-master\Songify-master\index.html

Comment: just use ./assets/images/

Comment: thnx that worked... can you give me the reason for that

Comment: You always need to supply the path of the image from the file you're calling it. As index.html file is calling the image and residing at Songify-master\Songify-master. 
At the same time images are sitting at assets/images/ which is the sub-folder of same directory. Hence I supplied the url of subdirectory only.